# my aem instance became inaccessible after configuring referrer filter

Tags: aem

I configured the referrer filter and I added get method also as filter method and saved. After that, my aem instance became inaccessible. Im not even able to access the url **localhost:4503/system/console/configMgr** to modify the referrer filter. May I know what can be done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have post requests working as expected you can try curling a correct config-

```
curl  -F "jcr:primaryType=sling:OsgiConfig"  -F filter.methods=[ \"POST\", \"PUT\", \"DELETE\"] -u admin:admin  http://localhost:4502/apps/system/config/org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter
```

Also, If you have access to file system, you can go to `crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/org/apache/sling/security/impl` and delete the file `ReferrerFilter.config` and restart your AEM instance. Default ReferrerFilter config  will be restored.